# Where can I find details on selinux Booleans

Tags: centos, security, openvpn, selinux

I'm running an openvpn server and I want to use SELinux.  When it's activated I see a few "denied" events in the logs.  I've used audit2allow to create a '.te' file. My question is about these lines in the file.

```
#============= openvpn_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'nis_enabled'
allow openvpn_t unreserved_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
```

I understand 'nis_enabled' boolean will allow this and other context requests.
Where can I find exactly what this boolean will allow?

What would you choose to do, enable the boolean or the policy?

EDIT:
Thank you @Michael Hampton.

```
semanage port -a -t openvpn_t -p tcp <myVpnPort>
```

Comment: In this case you don't need a policy module, just add your desired port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `semanage boolean --list | grep nis` to find a brief description on what it does and its status.

```
# semanage boolean -l | grep nis
nis_enabled                    (off  ,  off)  Allow nis to enabled
varnishd_connect_any           (off  ,  off)  Allow varnishd to connect any
```

You can find all the documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-booleans).

Edit: the OP indicated in a comment that specific info on what the booleans did was needed, so digging a bit deeper I found that

```
sesearch -b nis_enabled -A | grep -i openvpn
```

was the preferred answer.

Comment: I was looking for detailed information regarding individual booleans, like nis_enabled.

Comment: ok, maybe this: sesearch -b nis_enabled -A | grep -i openvpn ? On a fedora 30 system I get plenty of details of what the boolean does to openvpn contexts

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: glad to help. I modified my original answer, if you think this is the correct one to your question, feel free to mark it as the right one ;-)